# Discord.js restart command is not working (returns undefined error)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot with discord.js and my restart command is not working. By not working I mean, I get this error:

```
(node:41784) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '_timeouts' of undefined
```

My code is:

```js
const config = require('../../config.json');
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if(!config.owners.includes(message.author.id)) {
        return message.channel.send(`Only the bot owner can execute this command`)
    }

    message.channel.send(`Okay, I'll restart...`)
      .then(
        bot.destroy
    ).then(
        bot.login(config.token)
    )
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "restart",
    description: "Restarts the bot",
    usage: "restart",
    category: "dev"
};
```

If you can, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const config = require('../../config.json');
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    if(!config.owners.includes(message.author.id)) {
        return message.channel.send(`Only the bot owner can execute this command`)
    }

    message.channel.send(`Okay, I'll restart...`)
    .then(()=>bot.destroy()) // <<<<
    .then(()=>bot.login(config.token)) // <<<<
};

module.exports.help = {
    name: "restart",
    description: "Restarts the bot",
    usage: "restart",
    category: "dev"
};
```

`.then()` takes a function as argument, so you have to wrap the actions into a function.